# Match executable with path that might contain spaces

Tags: regex, path

We can assume that the whitespace will be escaped by `\`. 
Eveerything including the binary should be matched, excluding an optional list of arguments.
For example:

`C:\Program\ Folder\paint.exe -some arg` => `C:\Program Folder\paint.exe`

`convert lots of args` => `convert`

`/usr/bin/ls documents` => `/usr/bin/ls`

`/optional\ utils/util --help` => `/optional utils/util`

A solution for the default Java regex engine would be nice, but I can convert that if needed.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I fixed the `/usr/bin/ls` case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex might help:

`^(([^\s]|(\\ ))*)(?<!\\).*$`

However, it'll match the binaries *including* the escaped spaces. You'll have to un-escape the spaces later.

*UPD:* The result is in the 1st group.

Here is a working example: https://regex101.com/r/z5L3yz/1

**Explanation**

- `[^\s]` captures anything, except space characters
- `(\\ )` captures an escaped space
- `(([^\s]|(\\ ))*)` is a group that we're looking for (a binary name)
- After the group we're using a negative lookbehind `(?<!\\)` before anything which remains `.*`

Comment: This will match everything including arguments. Path without argument is in captured first group. Not sure if this is what OP wants.

Comment: Nice! Fantastic, that looks very good. The binary is available in group(1). I tried for some time but couldn't wrap my head around it.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex that matches name of the command that may include any number of escaped characters:

```
^[^\s\\]+(?:\\.[^\s\\]*)*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EpZmUw/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `[^\s\\]+`: Match 1+ characters that are not backslash and whitespace
- `(?:\\.[^\s\\]*)*`: Match 0 or more groups consisting of a backslash followed by an escaped character which is followed by 0+ characters that are not backslash and whitespace

Comment: Sorry, only a few seconds too late, I already accepted Ildar's solution. If someone wants to group(0) this is a very good one.

Comment: I never consider posting answers as race. If you care for performance then please look at **no of steps** taken in the regex you end of using in code.

Comment: Your regex is much smoother that the one I wrote :) And the # of steps is five times less.

Comment: you're right, 41 vs 206 steps ain't bad, I'll use yours

Comment: Won't match if path starts with escaped white character, but very nice. I was too slow with my solution :)

Comment: Can be solved by changing `+` to `*`. I didn't test all cases, but seems to work and it's way better than mine solution :)

Comment: @JánStibila: Yes I deliberately made it not match an escaped space at start because a command cannot start with a space.

Answer (score 0):

This will capture any string that may contain escaped white space characters. Any non escaped white space and everything after is not captured:

```
^((\\\s)*[^\s]?)+

^ - match begining of the line
 ( - begining 1st group
  ( - begining 2nd group
   \\\s - match "\ " (escape character and any white character after that)
       )* - end 2nd group - match any number of times
         [^\s]? - match anything that isn't white character one or zero occurences (we don't want it to eat escape character)
               )+ - end 1st group - match at least once
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Works correctly, but anubhava's answer uses less steps.

Comment: True, but won't match if path starts with escaped white space :)